# Mysterious warning appears unconsistently in my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

Every now and then, when I open the URL of [my Wordpress website](http://www.cosmetic-huebner.de), I get this line:

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://www.cosmetic-huebner.de:80 (Connection refused) in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 1008

The problem is that is not consistent. Sometimes comes, sometimes it doesn't.

What is happening?

**UPDATE:** In case anyone wonder that that line of wordpress code does: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2-branch/wp-includes/class-http.php#L1008

Comment: Is www.cosmetic-huebner.de your site, or is it trying to connect to an external site?

Comment: Have you looked at what it's trying to do on line 1008 of class-http.php? Can you post that as well?

Comment: This is the line: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2-branch/wp-includes/class-http.php#L1008

Comment: Thanks -- didn't realize Wordpress was on GH. If it was happening all of the time, I'd be inclined to think you may have hit a bug, but if its intermittent, my first thought is a network/connection issue. Any other issues with your site? Is it on a shared host?

Comment: It is my own VPS. I have other sites that dont show that problem...

Comment: It looks like this site is trying to load something from itself via tcp with the WP_Http_Streams class. Some plugins and themes do that. It may be wise to try disabling plugins one by one until the problem goes away. If that works you'll know which plugin causes the problem.

Comment: Deleting the old themes, seemed to do the trick. Thanks